# Match regex multiple times

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to construct a regex that matches a pattern multiple times?

For example searching for `ff` in `fff` would give two matches. Their starting position would be 0 and 1 respectively.

Comment: You're right Xavier. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this.

```
>>> import re
>>> [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r'f(?=f)', 'fff')]
[0, 1]
```

Comment: The function `finditer` only returns the `non-overlapping` instances. "Return an iterator yielding MatchObject instances over all non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string" see http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: @Desolator Have you read the docs of [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) that you used in your answer?

Comment: The drawback is `m.groups()` is no longer very useful

Comment: This works great on small instances. But it's too slow when the pattern length is >70000 characters long on a big text 6-7 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use [`findall(string[, pos[, endpos]])`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

> Similar to the findall() function, using the compiled pattern, but
>   also accepts optional pos and endpos parameters that limit the search
>   region like for match().

i.e. Each time you will begin search from the `m.start()` of the previous match `+ 1`.